# PostgreSQL - Delete values with conditions

Tags: postgresql

In a `PostgreSQL` table, I wan't to delete some values with conditions. This conditions are based on the begining of a field with a `substr`. In my example, I want to delete the values ​​not starting with '01' or '02' or '03'. When I first run a `SELECT` on my values with conditions, it's ok.

**Sample data**

```
id  |  serial_number
---------------------
1   | 01A
2   | 01B
3   | 02A
4   | 02B
5   | 03A
6   | 03B
7   | 03C
8   | 04A
9   | 05A
10  | 06A
```

**Example of a selection**

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE substr(serial_number, 1, 2) LIKE '01' OR substr(serial_number, 1, 2) LIKE '02' OR substr(serial_number, 1, 2) LIKE '03'
```

But when I apply the same conditions in a `DELETE` and add a negation, it removes eveything. I need to change operators from `OR` to `AND`.

**Delete with same condition (not expected result)**

```
DELETE FROM my_table
WHERE substr(serial_number, 1, 2) NOT LIKE '01' OR substr(serial_number, 1, 2) NOT LIKE '02' AND substr(serial_number, 1, 2) NOT LIKE '03'
```

**Delete with different operators (expected result)**

```
DELETE FROM my_table
WHERE substr(serial_number, 1, 2) NOT LIKE '01' AND substr(serial_number, 1, 2) NOT LIKE '02' AND substr(serial_number, 1, 2) NOT LIKE '03'
```

How multiple conditions could be true with a `AND` ? It's not cumulative. I don't understand why I need to change operators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some basic boolean math:

```
True OR False = True
True AND False = False
```

Consider a single record in your table with value `01A`. You don't want to delete this since it's in your list `01, 02, 03`.

Running your logic:

```
substr(serial_number, 1, 2) NOT LIKE '01' = False
substr(serial_number, 1, 2) NOT LIKE '02' = True
```

Taking that back to the Boolean logic above you'll see that `False OR True` = `True` which means we delete the record. However, switching to an AND means `False AND True` = `False` and your record `01A` is retained as expected.

This is a common issue when dealing with negation and booleans in that it doesn't match how we use `OR` in english.

Consider a store that cells gift cards in values 20, 50 and 100 dollars:

> "Can you go get a gift card for Chili's restaurant. I can't remember
> what dollar amounts they sell, but I don't need the 20 dollar one or
> the 50 dollar one"

We all understand perfectly well that they don't want the 20 or the 50, but rather the 100 dollar gift card. But in boolean logic the person being asked would return with ALL the gift cards available as 20 != 50 and 50 != 20 and 100 != 50 (and 20). So the OR sees a `TRUE` for at least one of the conditions specified regardless of the gift card amount.

Comment: As you said this usage of negation and booleans doesn't match with natural language, it confused me. Thank you for this well-illustrated example and the detailed explanations.

Comment: Nice explanation. I must be turning into a crusty engineer (back in my day...) because boolean logic is so ingrained that it doesn't occur to me that boolean logic differs from natural language. Does this mean I have to cut more slack to young engineers?

Comment: @bfris Every time I think I have it down I encounter some negation thing that blows my mind. I had a hell of a time getting my head wrapped around `NOT LIKE ALL (<list>)` vs `NOT LIKE ANY (<list>)` in Teradata. I still have to really sit down and think about it before I use those.